# Toggling the "highlighted bordering" around a user selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that generates a simple excel template for a user. The code locks and protects all cells not in "A2:A" and makes them unselectable. But, after this code runs, the user no longer gets the highlighted bordering around a selected cell. Is there some way to make sure this is enabled in the code?

```
With ws1
    .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    With .Cells
        .Locked = True
        .Borders.Color = vbWhite
    End With

    With .Columns("A")
        .Locked = False
        .Borders.Color = vbBlack
        .ColumnWidth = 20
    End With

    With .Range("A1")
        .Value = "MPID"
        .Interior.Color = 14277081
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Locked = True
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with restricting Excel sheets, you sort of have to approach it in reverse logic. Everything will be restricted by default, once you click on or activate a Macro that restricts the Worksheet. So you first have to select and change the "Locked" value on the cells or range to false first. You should then set everything else how you want it to be, and the last step is to actively restrict the sheet. This should give you what you want:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'unprotect the column that you don't want to restrict
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False

    With ws1.Range("A1")
        .Value = "MPID"
        .Interior.Color = 14277081
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    With ws1.Columns("A")
        .Borders.Color = vbBlack
        .ColumnWidth = 20
    End With

    ws1.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ws1.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

    Set ws1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! So is it the UserInterfaceOnly statement that is disabling the user selection highlighting?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't checked, but this is the thing... experiment! Chuck that statement in there, run it, and see what happens. That'll give you the answer to that question.

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference. I guess its just the ordering of formatting, locking and protecting. Still scratching my head a bit over it. But it works and I'm very grateful. Thanks again!